# Restangular error returning String

Tags: rest, restangular, spring-restcontroller

I have a REST method that create a document and returns the generatedId.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/document", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String prelievo(
        @RequestBody(required = true) Document document)
        throws Exception {
    return deliveryService.insertDocument(document);
}
```

the method works fine (I tested it whit postman) but when I call the method with RestAngular

```
this.Restangular.all('delivery/document').post(document)
```

I get

```
SyntaxError: Unexpected number
   at Object.parse (native)
```

I think the problem is that RestAngulartries to convert the String in a Json object.
The only solution that I found is to return and Array of String instead of a single object.
How can I specify to RestAngular how to parse the response?

Answer (score 0):

This happens when backend service is not returning valid json file, response should always be valid json, so you cannot return just

```
1
```

but you have to return

```
{ id : 1 }
```